# Adding a new field in contact page of ESS

Tags: symfony1, orangehrm

I need to add a new field in contact details with a text area. I tried to edit the files [suggested in orange HRM forum](http://forum.orangehrm.com/viewtopic.php?f=22&t=9785).

I am getting an error exception `InvalidArgumentException` with message

> Widget does not exist

Answer (score 2):

As I tried, I can add new field, here the ways:, I'm newbie in symfony :)

This is for Personal Details in PIM

1. Add name field on schema.yml (field that you wanna create)
2. Create that field in database (map between field in schema.yml and database)
3. Use cmd, and run "php symfony doctrine:build-model"
4. Create the form in (for example) in BaseEmployeeForm.class.php
5. Create for View in viewPersonalDetailSucces.php
6. Edit in EmployeeDao.php at function savePersonalDetails

Comment: This worked for me. Furthermore, when you make changes in .js(for validation),css files it is important that you make the changes in both symfony/web and symfony/web/webres..  directory and clear the cache.

Comment: @phedonrousou Yes it is write you saved a day 4 me. what is this webres.. directory stands for.

Comment: I think it is a folder that has caches the web elements such as javascripts and css files

Comment: @phedonrousou Can you please read this and reply http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21479320/orange-hrm-3-1-leave-list-customization

Answer (score 1):

Work perfectly on my side with OrangeHRM 3.1.1,

1. Add pim module schema
2. Modify table as schema config
3. Modify EmployeeDao.php on Widget and Information
4. Modify viewPersonalDetails form and template.
5. Done.